# property width: 100% not fitting printable area with position fixed when bootstrap included

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to print an HTML page with Bootstrap styles but when I include the link for Bootstrap the div with `position: fixed` and `width: 100%` can't fit the printable area. When I remove the link for Bootstrap the div fits the printable area.

When I remove Bootstrap link

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            @media print {
                html, body {
                    margin:0; 
                    padding: 0;
                }
                @page {
                    margin:0; 
                    padding: 0;
                    size:  210mm;
                }
                .content-div {
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    background-color: rgb(10, 3, 3);
                    z-index: 999;
                }                                
            }            
            
            
        </style>

    </head>
    
    <body style="width: 210mm;">
        <div class="content-div"></div>
       
        <script>
            print()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The results
[image]

With Bootstrap link in the head here is the results

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style>
            @media print {
                html, body {
                    margin:0; 
                    padding: 0;
                }
                @page {
                    margin:0; 
                    padding: 0;
                    size:  210mm;
                }
                .content-div {
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    background-color: rgb(10, 3, 3);
                    z-index: 999;
                }                                
            }            
            
            
        </style>

    </head>
    
    <body style="width: 210mm;">
        <div class="content-div"></div>
       
        <script>
            print()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Why is the black div with `width: 100%` not fitting the printable area when Bootstrap is included?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the Bootstrap.min.css file, I found the @media print which need to be overridden.

```
<style>
    @media print {
        body {
            min-width: 210mm !important
        }
    }
</style>
```

by adding `min-width: 210mm !important` to the body under media print, it works